# getting max value and its corresponding 3 columns from a table belonging to a time frame

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

[image]I have a table in sql server which has data values and timestamp for every 15 min interval. from jan 2015 to june 2016. Every 96 interval set (15 min interval,so 96 in 24 hrs) has one data value which is highest of that day (24 hrs). I have another 3 columns called a,b,c. I need to find that max value of every 96 interval set and their respective A,B,C values. I tried to use max and group by but couldn't get the exact number. Can some body please help me on this.

I have posted the snap shot of how the data looks. so in this case, you are looking at Jan 02, I need the Maximum value of KW, for the whole 96 intervals.And more importantly, I need the Phase a, phase b,phase c values of the corresponding max value.

Comment: Can you post sample data and what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the maximum each day.  You can use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(timestamp as date)
                                order by onedatavalue desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanting to get the max value each day, you can just use a Max within sub query like this:

```
select * from DATATABLE as D 
where KW = (Select MAX(KW) from DATATABLE 
            where DAY(KEY_POINT_DTTM_15MIN) = DAY(D.KEY_POINT_DTTM_15MIN))
```

I guess you're using max() but you forgot the DAY() function..